# Woocommerce - Change price range to default variation price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to Change the price range to only the default variation that I chose, price range is confusing for some customers especially the prices, I tried a lot of methods, and almost every question here in Stackoverflow and nothing solve the issue.
I'm using WordPress 5.5
Flatsome theme 3.12.2
Woocommerce 4.3.2
Any ideas how to make it possible.
Thanks

Comment: Even if you *"tried a lot of methods, and almost every question here in Stackoverflow and nothing solve the issue"*, we expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt. Please note that StackOverFlow is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this in your custome function php file:

```
function custom_default_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $pav){
        $defautl=true;
        foreach($product->get_default_attributes() as $defkey=>$defval){
            if($pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey]!=$defval){
                $defautl=false;             
            }   
        }
        if($defautl){
            $price = $pav['display_price'];         
        }
    }   
    return wc_price($price);
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'custom_default_variation_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_default_variation_price', 10, 2 );
```